# Does a US national need a medical visa to receive treatment in Australia?

Tags: visas, us-citizens, australia, medical-tourism

I'm travelling to Australia soon to receive a medical procedure from a gastroenterologist who provides a treatment not available in the US (which I intend to pay for out of pocket). I'm also visiting as a tourist and plan to go to beaches and restaurants and just kind of enjoy my time in a completely new place.  Is the medical treatment visa required for this or will an ETA suffice?

I've never traveled outside of North America, and never to a country that requires a visa. I'm unsure whether the purpose of the visa is purely to grant entry or if it governs the things that I can and cannot do while in the country (beyond working, which I'm pretty sure I can't do on an ETA).  I'd hate to arrive and be denied entry if it turns out I have the wrong kind of entry permission. The homeaffairs.gov.au website isn't particularly clear for my situation.

Comment: What I can tell you is that I have been to Australia as a tourist many times, and a couple of times I had to see a doctor while I was there, and this is obviously something that you can do. My guess (but I didn't even know there was a "medical treatment" visa, and I haven't looked it up) is that this visa is for people who need a treatment, can justify it, and would not granted other types of visas.

Comment: @jcaron: The question is really not whether they can see a doctor while there, but whether they can **enter** Australia if their primary purpose is to receive treatment and they don't have the specific visa for that.

Comment: I'm pretty sure anything that is not "working" is fine with a tourist visa, but I'll let those in the know answer, that's why it was just a comment.

Comment: @user2097846 One consideration is how long your medical treatment is expected to last. A medical treatment visa allows the holder to remain in Australia until the treatment is completed https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/602-  To enter visa-free with an eTA gives you up to 3 months per visit in a 12 month period https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/601-

Comment: Are you a US citizen?

Comment: @NateEldredge yes.

Answer (score 1):

An [Electronic Travel Authority (subclass 601) visa](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/601-) permits you to engage in tourist or business visitor activities while in Australia.  If you **intend** to travel to Australia for activities other than tourist or business visitor activities, then your ETA is liable for cancellation under [paragraph 2.43(ea) of the *Migration Regulations 1994*](https://www.legislation.gov.au/Details/F2018C00544/Html/Volume_1#_Toc522021921). This paragraph provides (emphasis added) that a visa can be cancelled if:

> in the case of a Subclass 601 (Electronic Travel Authority) visa—that, despite the grant of the visa, the Minister is satisfied that the visa holder:
>
> (i)  did not have, at the time of the grant of the visa, an intention **only** to stay in, or visit, Australia temporarily for the tourism or business purposes for which the visa was granted; or
>
> (ii)  has ceased to have that intention;

If your intention to travel to Australia is to seek medical treatment, then you should consider a [Medical Treatment (subclass 602) visa](https://www.homeaffairs.gov.au/trav/visa-1/602-).

Comment: This is the by the book answer, and since the subclass 602 visa is free, if you're not in a hurry you can play it safe and apply for it.  However, in practice it would be *exceedingly* unlikely that you would have your ETA cancelled if you come to Australia for tourism & medical appointments -- the intent of that clause is to stop people from *working* illegally.

Comment: @jpatokal If the intent of the Australian government was to allow people to enter for medical treatment on an ETA then they would not have created the 602 visa.

Comment: @DJClayworth I'm not sure how you draw that conclusion, since the 602 visa seems primarily targeted at people who do not qualify for ETAs.